# how can i fix python contour problems?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

```
import cv2
image= cv2.imread('1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, thesh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, 0)
countours= cv2.findContours(thesh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
image = cv2.drawContours(image, countours,-1, (0,255, 0), 4)
cv2.imshow('', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

and the result was

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/robin/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello", line 5, in 
>       image = cv2.drawContours(image, countours,-1, (0,255, 0), 4) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2509:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function
>   'cv::drawContours'

---

i'm writing a script to find contours but the error continues to show up how can i fix it?

Comment: What's that [1] at the end of findcontour?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [0] instead of [1] in `cv2.findContours`.